# Entry widget validation difference between classic and ttk widgets

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I have discovered an unexpected difference in Entry widget validation between classic and ttk widgets in Python 3.5.

Using classic widgets:

```
from tkinter import *

def validate(reason):
  print("--> validate:", reason)
  return(True)

def change():
  var.set("data")

root = Tk()
vc = root.register(validate)
var = StringVar()
Entry(root, textvariable = var, validate = "all", validatecommand = (vc, "%V")).pack()
Button(root, text = "Change", command = change).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Using ttk widgets:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
... same code as above
```

With classic widgets, when the "Change" button is pressed, the validate function is called with reason == "forced", which seems to comply with the Tk doc. With ttk widgets, when the "Change" button is pressed, the validate function is not called. Otherwise the validate function seems to have the equivalent behavior for both cases. Anybody have an idea if this is a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a feature. According to the [official ttk documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/ttk_entry.htm#M-validate):

> **DIFFERENCES FROM TK ENTRY WIDGET VALIDATION**
>
> The standard Tk entry widget automatically disables validation (by
>   setting -validate to none) if the -validatecommand or -invalidcommand
>   modifies the entry's value. The Tk themed entry widget only disables
>   validation if one of the validation scripts raises an error, or if
>   -validatecommand does not return a valid boolean value. (Thus, it is not necessary to re-enable validation after modifying the entry value
>   in a validation script).
>
> In addition, the standard entry widget invokes validation whenever the
>   linked -textvariable is modified; the Tk themed entry widget does not.